# Need help to setup google merchant request

Tags: java, sandbox, payment

I'm trying to develop a simple online shop application using Java, and I got a hand of google for online payment.
I just signed up for google merchant, and already have got my issuer and secret code.
But I've got some question about the sample provided by google, the following code is the sample merchant requests.

```
private String getJWT() throws InvalidKeyException, SignatureException {
  JsonToken token = null;
  token = createToken();
  return token.serializeAndSign();
}

private JsonToken createToken() throws InvalidKeyException{
  //Current time and signing algorithm
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  HmacSHA256Signer signer = new HmacSHA256Signer(ISSUER, null, SIGNING_KEY.getBytes());

  //Configure JSON token
  JsonToken token = new JsonToken(signer);
  token.setAudience("Google");
  token.setParam("typ", "google/payments/inapp/item/v1");
  token.setIssuedAt(new Instant(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
  token.setExpiration(new Instant(cal.getTimeInMillis() + 60000L));

  //Configure request object
  JsonObject request = new JsonObject();
  request.addProperty("name", "Piece of Cake");
  request.addProperty("description", "Virtual chocolate cake to fill your virtual tummy");
  request.addProperty("price", "10.50");
  request.addProperty("currencyCode", "USD");
  request.addProperty("sellerData", "user_id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j");

  JsonObject payload = token.getPayloadAsJsonObject();
  payload.add("request", request);

  return token;
}
```

Everything is clear except this line

```
request.addProperty("sellerData", "user_id:1224245,offer_code:3098576987,affiliate:aksdfbovu9j");
```

Would someone explain how am I supposed to set these? and what are these?!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it :D
`https://developers.google.com/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#jwt`
It's optional field, google sends the same data when the transaction is success to issuer postback uri.

Comment: be ready to check source code of google api clients. just found that docs and samples have mistake: one of the vars containing string, but actual api-client library expects array